Arrastrar y soltar en un script
Tengo un script que lee un fichero, le suma 1 a una variable y lo guarda.
   library(readxl)
    
    dat <- read_excel("dat.xlsx")
    
    dat$Suma1 <-dat$Col1 + 1
    
    library(writexl)
    
    write_xlsx(dat, "dat_suma.xlsx")

En windows, ¿hay alguna forma de arrastrar el fichero dat.xlsx sobre el script.R y que este se ejecute?

Para conseguir el efecto drag & drop necesitarías un "server" que escuche esos eventos, lamentablemente con un Script R puro  no se puedes, con Shiny si, ya dispones de un fileinput que permite "drag and drop"
